# Crystal Report Server 5 CAL

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I was planning on using Crystal Report Server 2008 for my web application. It says that I can buy 5 CAL. It also says that CALs are for concurrent users and can have 100 recipients. What does that mean? does that mean that 100 users can view reports simultaneously just using 5 CALs? Is it 100 recipients for all 5 CAL or 100 recipient per CAL?

Answer (score 1):

According to [their documentation:](http://www.businessobjects.com/pdf/whitepapers/crxi_licensing_whitepaper.pdf)

> Licensing for internal corporate deployment End-user report viewing
>   is licensed through concurrent access licenses (CAL). This means that
>   a set number of end users can simultaneously connect to Crystal 
>   Reports Server. For example, a five CAL license enables five end users
>   to be simultaneously logged on to the system. The sixth end user that
>   attempts to log on will be denied access until one of the first five
>   user logs off of his/her session times out.

So, issue part the first: one concurrent user per concurrent access license.

Issue part the second: the allowed number of *publishing* recipients. From their [licensing document:](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/information-infrastructure/sapcrystalserver/licensing/index.epx)

> The number of publishing recipients varies according to the number of
>   concurrent access licenses (CAL) licenses.
>
> - 5 CAL, 100 recipients
> - 10 CAL, 250 recipients
> - 20 CAL, 1000 recipients
> - 250 CAL, Unlimited recipients

So, for 5 CAL, you receive 100 recipients in accordance with this tiered model. Each "recipient" appears to be a single user that can access Crystal Reports' [data-driven publishing feature.](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/information-infrastructure/sapcrystalserver/featuresfunctions/index.epx)

Note that some additional restrictions may apply. For the version of Crystal Reports Server mentioned in the documentation above, a maximum of 20 CAL is allowed per deployment.